# Trying to refresh a datagrid on main form after closing form 2

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, forms, datagrid

I am having an issue with a datagrid and and getting it to refresh when new data is added.  The way I am trying to get it to work is.

On main form, a button("add") click event which shows a form2 with fields to input the new data into the table which is in main form.  Once the data is entered and then a button("Insert/Add") click event which closes form2 and display that new entered data in main form data grid.

The problem is that I do not know exactly how the datagrid be refresh or update to show the new information.  Any help would be appreciated.

MAIN FORM:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class Main : Form
{


    public Main()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'userLoginDataSet.WeaponData' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.weaponDataTableAdapter.Fill(this.userLoginDataSet.WeaponData);

    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        AddWeapon aw = new AddWeapon();
        aw.Show();
    }

}

}
```

ADDWEAPON FORM:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
public partial class AddWeapon : Form
{
    public AddWeapon()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\brmcbrid\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\UserLogin.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT into WeaponData values('" + serialNumber.Text + "','" + brand.Text + "','" + model.Text + "','" + caliber.Text + "','" + type.Text + "' , '" + dateAcquired.Text + "', '" + dateSold.Text + "', '" + purchasePrice.Text + "', '" + sellPrice.Text + "', '" + notes.Text + "')", con);



        this.Close();
    }


}
}
```

Comment: The requirement seems very close to this one : [Reload data using TableAdapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403150/reload-data-using-tableadapter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options you have. All of them deal with having a reference of the main form in the child form.

**Option #1:**

Pass the Main form instance as a constructor in the child form:

In Main form code:

```
    AddWeapon aw = new AddWeapon(this); // pass this, the main form
    aw.Show();
```

In child form, have a private field of the main form and an additional constructor.

```
public partial class AddWeapon : Form
{
    private Main _mainForm;

    public AddWeapon()
    {
     InitializeComponent();
     }

     public AddWeapon(Main mainForm) : this()
     {
      this._mainForm = mainForm;
     }

     // remaining code.

     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\brmcbrid\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\UserLogin.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT into WeaponData values('" + serialNumber.Text + "','" + brand.Text + "','" + model.Text + "','" + caliber.Text + "','" + type.Text + "' , '" + dateAcquired.Text + "', '" + dateSold.Text + "', '" + purchasePrice.Text + "', '" + sellPrice.Text + "', '" + notes.Text + "')", con);

      // call a public method on the main form that can update the data.
      this._mainForm.UpdateData();

      this.Close();
     }
  }
```

**Option #2:**

Instead of passing the reference of the main form in the constructor, you could also set it via a public property of the child form and do the same.

```
    AddWeapon aw = new AddWeapon();
    aw.Main = this;

    aw.Show();
```

**Option #3:**

This option has no form instance connection. What you do is raise an event when the child form has inserted the data and have the parent form subscribe to this event.

in the parent form

```
    AddWeapon aw = new AddWeapon();
    aw.OnDataInserted += this.DataInserted;
    aw.Show();
```

in the child form,

```
public event EventHandler DataInserted;
```

and then after the insert

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\brmcbrid\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\UserLogin.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT into WeaponData values('" + serialNumber.Text + "','" + brand.Text + "','" + model.Text + "','" + caliber.Text + "','" + type.Text + "' , '" + dateAcquired.Text + "', '" + dateSold.Text + "', '" + purchasePrice.Text + "', '" + sellPrice.Text + "', '" + notes.Text + "')", con);

    if (this.DataInserted != null)
    {
     this.DataInserted();
    }

    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Regarding Option 3.  For this.DataInserted(); in the IF STATEMENT on child form I am getting an error.  Says that is does not take 0 arguements.

Comment: Yes.. Pass this, null to it

Comment: Call it like  this.DataInserted(this, null)

Answer (score 0):

You can write code to refresh your grid on activate event of Main form as shown below:

```
    private void Main_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // write your code here
    }
```